# In Maui what is the equivilant of Close() from Maui.Extensions popup in Mopups

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to close a Mopups popup page with a ButtonClick but can't find a command todo this. In Maui.Extensions you could just use the Close() function but this isn't in Mopups :-(

This works in Maui.Extensions

```
private void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

---

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
    <ShellContent Title="Options" Icon="Help_24_w.png" Route="Options" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Options}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Help...." Icon="Help_24_w.png" Route="Help" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Help}" />
    <!--<ShellContent Title="About" Icon="info_24_w.png" Route="puAbout" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:puAbout}" />-->
</FlyoutItem>
<!--<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
    <ShellContent Title="Login/Logout" Icon="logouticon.png" Route="puLogin"    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:puLogin}" />
</FlyoutItem>-->

<MenuItem Text="About" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" IconImageSource="info_24_w.png" Clicked="AboutClicked"/>
<MenuItem Text="Login/Logout" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" IconImageSource="logouticon.png" Clicked="LoginClicked"/>
```

....xaml.cs

```
public  void LoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false; 
    var page = new puLogin();
    MopupService.Instance.PushAsync((PopupPage)page);
}
public  void AboutClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
    var page = new puAbout();
    MopupService.Instance.PushAsync((PopupPage)page);
}
```

Comment: Use Mpopup.Instance.PopAsync

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Maui and struggling with navigation. I'm using Flyout for nav and there is no click event attached to the FlyouItem. I use ContentTemplate to call pages from the flyout. I want to use one of the flyout items to show the popup (a login page) but can't call the code "await MopupService.Instance.PushAsync((PopupPage)page);" I can get this code working from a page button click but not a FlyoutItem.

Comment: Your question is about how to close a popup, now you are asking about how to open one?  And what do you mean you **can't** "call the code" - why not?  Is there an error or exception?

Comment: Sorry, as I said I'm new to Maui. There are several ways to call a popup. The one I was using was through Flyouts ContentTemplate. Doing it that way excludes the use of PopAsync to close it.
I need to get the Flyout to call C# code to call the popup with PushAsync so I can close it with PopAsync but I can't find a way to call C# code from a Flyout.
I have since used MenuItem in my Flyout which has a Clicked event that I use to call the code. 
It's not pretty and it would have been a lot easier if the Mopup had a close method.
Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code

Comment: You can try the MenuFlyoutItem to use the click button.

Answer (score 1):

```
MopupService.Instance.RemovePageAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pop method to close the popup.

```
MopupService.Instance.PopAsync();
```